# Constructing HTTP Chunks from ByteBuf in Netty 4

Tags: java, netty, netty4

I have a Netty 3 codebase with an HTTP Message decoder which extends ReplayingDecoder, and I need to migrate code which analyzes the chunks of the message, which means I need to get the chunks.

```
protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Channel channel, 
                        ByteBuf buffer, State state) {

    //...

    HttpChunk chunk = new DefaultHttpChunk(buffer.readBytes(toRead));

    //...

}
```

From what I've gathered, I need to use HttpChunkedInput instead, but creating one is surprisingly difficult.

```
                                           //requires an InputStream...
HttpChunkedInput hc = new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedStream(...));

//but this seems really clunky/too awkward to be right.
HttpChunkedInput hc = new HttpChunkedInput(new ChunkedStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer.array()));
```

ByteBuf doesn't seem to have a way to dump out a stream directly. Am I missing a Util class API that would be better? I did find there's a new [EmbeddedChannel](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/embedded/EmbeddedChannel.html) class which can simply readInbound() like [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=bazelbuild%2Fbazel%2Fbazel-master%2Fsrc%2Ftest%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fgoogle%2Fdevtools%2Fbuild%2Flib%2Fremote%2Fhttp%2FHttpUploadHandlerTest.java), but I'm not sure I should be changing the types just for that or casting the bare Channel to an EmbeddedChannel to get out of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Netty 4.x onwards comes with an out of the box HTTP codec which unless you use an HTTP aggregation handler will give you HTTP chunks as `HttpContent` objects.

This example shows how to write a handler that received such chunks:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/a329857ec20cc1b93ceead6307c6849f93b3f101/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http/snoop/HttpSnoopServerHandler.java#L60